# Authentication in passport.js , used with angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing

I came to know the use of authenticate method in passport.js from the below link
http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/

In my project I have the below code:

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
        passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
            if (err) { console.log(err); return next(err) }
            if (!user) {
                return res.json(400, info);
            }
            req.logIn(user, function(err) {
                if (err) { return next(err); }
                return res.json(200, {user_id: user._id, url:"/user/home"});
            });
        })(req, res, next);
    });
```

I have a call to the /login url in another file, like below

```
 $http.post('/login', $scope.user).
              success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $window.location.href= data.url ? data.url : '/';
                $scope.view.loading = false;
              }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data);
                $scope.view.loading = false;
                $scope.view.submitted = true;
                $scope.view.serverError=data.message ? data.message : "Server Error!";
              });
```

My doubt here is , how come the passport.authenticate is aware of the user credentials. 
While calling http.post, we are also sending $scope.user. But that is only 'data'. How come passport.authenticate is aware of the object 'user'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not 100% sure of what you're asking exactly, but I'll give it a shot.

You are responsible for telling Passport if a username/password pair matches, and then giving Passport the user object that corresponds to the given username (or email or whatever). This is done in: `passport.use(new LocalStrategy( ... ));` where you specify this logic. (You can find example code on the official website [here](http://passportjs.org/guide/username-password/) on how to do this.) Passport then serialises this user object in the session, again by logic that you specify:

```
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    // Only store the user id in the session
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    // Find the user with the given id
    User.find(id).done(function (err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});
```

The `user` object that passport passes to you in the callback function to `passport.authenticate` is the very same `user` object that you gave passport as a result of the local strategy.

So here's the breakdown of events:

1. You POST username/password (or email/password) pair to /login.
2. The request is received by Express and routed to the appropriate handler.
3. You execute `passport.authenticate(...)` by giving it the `req`, `res`, and `next` objects given to you from the handler.
4. Passport executes your login logic that you specified in `passport.use(new LocalStrategy(...))`. If it was given a valid `user` object as a result of the logic process, then passport will pass this object to the callback function so that you can return back details of the user (or whatever).